# MongoDB + Node.js: unable to insert date properly

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I′ve been using [node-mongoskin](https://github.com/guileen/node-mongoskin) to connect this two. Everything was ok until I queried some "date" field which I think should be returned as javascript′s `Date` object. But result′s type was string, which is odd (for me) and inconvenient.

Inserting looks something like this:

```
var doc = {
  date: new Date(),
  info: 'Some info'
}
db.users.insert( doc, {safe: true}, function(err, res) {
  ...
});
```

And result of above is (without `_id` field):

```
{ "date" : "Mon Oct 24 2011 18:00:57 GMT+0400 (MSK)", "info": "Some info" }
```

However, inserting with MongoDB Shell works just fine, except type of field is `ISODate`

```
> db.things.insert({ date: new Date() }); db.things.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4eae9f2a34067b92db8deb40"), "date" : ISODate("2011-10-31T13:14:18.947Z") }
```

So, the question is: how should I insert documents to query date fields as `Date` object? What I want is setting fields on database-server-side. I just send something like null-fields, and db-server setting those for me using default mongo′s mechanisms.

Inserting timestamps (as [native MongoDB timestamp](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Timestamp+data+type)) is also a problem, but it′s not such a big deal.

PS: No luck going through mongoskin and [mongodb-native](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/) docs.

Comment: I think, date problem gone with update (not sure whose: driver's of mongo's). Still wondering how timestamps should be correctly inserted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was probably some bug in my code or the mongo driver. Now, the following works just fine:

```
db.collection.insert({d: new Date()});
```

Timestamps support described here: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/timestamp.html.

Comment: Thanks. As a side note, do **not** use ```new Date().toISOString()``` when inserting into MongoDB database (instead just use ```new Date()```) because MongDB already does the conversion for you and using .toISOString() will make .find() operators or $gte operators on the database fail

Answer (score 0):

ISODate is the native way for mongo to store date. I use node-mongodb-native npm module and I store/retrieve javascript Date using new Date() idiom like in your examples. I don't know if it's a recent correction because I started node and Mongo in 2012, but using date was pretty straightforward for me.

Comment: Do **not** use ```new Date().toISOString()``` when inserting into MongoDB database (instead just use ```new Date()```) because MongDB already does the conversion for you and using .toISOString() will make .find() operators or $gte operators on the database fail

Comment: @YiXiangChong:How to get matched date documents from mongodb?

Comment: Hi @PappaS here is one way to get matched date documents from mongodb:
```
var today = new Date("2020-06-16");
var tomorrow = new Date("2020-06-17");
var out = "documents_today";
agg_query = [
 {
  $match: { _timestamp: {$gte: today, $lt: tomorrow}},
 },
 {
  $out: out
 }
];
db.documents_collection.aggregate(agg_query);
db.documents_today.find().count();
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript code:

```
    collection.insert({"className"     : "models.Action", 
                       "title"         : "Email",
                       "description"   : "How are you today?",
                       "creationDate"  :  new Date("Fry, 4 May 2012 10:30:08 +0200 (CEST)"),
                       "creator"       : dbref },
```

produced in mongoDB

```
db.action.find({"title":"Email"})
> db.action.find({"title":"Email"})
{ "className" : "models.Action", "title" : "Email", "description" : "How are you today?", "creationDate" : ISODate("2012-05-04T08:30:08Z"), "creator" : { "$ref" : "person", "$id" : ObjectId("4f995e4824ac8d68f63adf69") }, "_id" : ObjectId("4fa79e2e92c2a19a09000002") }
```

Comment: Thanks. But as I noted in question comment, dates insertion is ok. But how timestamps are inserted (in [mongodb format](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Timestamp+data+type)). I guess it could be done with `collection.insert( {ts: new mongoskin.Timestamp()} )`.