# How to save datetime as BSON Date using Node driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

I'm using the Node MongoDB driver to collect analytics for my website and send them to MongoLab. How does one insert the current datetime into a document so it can later be used to do aggregation in Mongo?

To be clear, here is the code:

```
var query = {};
query['date_time'] = new Date();
Db.connect(mongoUri, function (err, db) {
        if (!err) {
            db.collection(analyticsCollection, function (err, coll) {
                if (!err) {
                    coll.save(query, {safe:true}, function (err, result) {
                        db.close();
                        res.send(200,result);
                        //console.log(result);
                    });
                } else {
                    res.json(503,{errno:503,msg:'error: collection does not exist.'});
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.json(503,{errno:503,msg:'error: database does not exist.'});
        }
    });
```

The MongoDB documentation describes how to create a BSON date in the mongo shell, but not in the Node driver and I can't find it in the Node driver docs either.

Comment: Seems like this thread has the answer you're looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954381/mongodb-node-js-unable-to-insert-date-properly

Comment: When I follow that thread, I get a field that looks like: "date_time": {
        "$date": "2013-06-15T02:03:44.912Z"
    } and this throws an error during aggregation ""errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type String to Date""

Comment: My experience is directly conflicting with the note that was addeed above my post about this already being answered. Please try it for yourself! Specifically try aggregating on the "date_time" field that is created by the above insert.

Comment: Can you share your aggregation code?

Comment: db.analytics.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{day:{$dayOfMonth:"$datetime"}}}}])

Comment: I understand that some will say you need to use $project, but I have done this aggregation with only a $group operator, when I inserted documents with the Ruby MongoDB driver. I just would like if someone can tell me if this is possible with the Node driver, and if so, how to do it. If $project must be used, then I would like to know that as well.

Comment: I should also point out that my original question is how to insert a BSON type date using the Node driver. So far, whatever I have tried has resulted in a BSON string of some sort. How do you insert a BSON date type? This has nothing to do with aggregation, which is a separate (albeit relevant) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what I wanted to do. This seems kind of klugey to me, so if anyone can find a better way, please let me know. My solution uses the underscore.js library:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
vary query = {}
query['foo'] = 'bar'

Db.connect(mongoUri, function (err, db) {
        if (!err) {
            db.collection(analyticsCollection, function (err, coll) {
                if (!err) {
                    coll.save(_.extend(query,{"datetime":new Date()}), {safe:true}, function (err, result) {
                        db.close();
                        res.send(200,result);
                        //console.log(result);
                    });
                } else {
                    res.json(503,{errno:503,msg:'error: collection does not exist.'});
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.json(503,{errno:503,msg:'error: database does not exist.'});
        }
    });
```

Now I can do the aggregation (without needing to use the $project operator):

```
> db.analytics.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{day:{$dayOfMonth:"$datetime"}}}}])
{ "result" : [ { "_id" : { "day" : 15 } } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

Hope this helps someone.