# Node.js to MongoDB: find by Date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, bson

Problem with find Date from Node to MongoDB:

It's been said MongoDB might not be storing a Date object, but a string, but I'm not sure how to check, or how to fix that.

In my turnys.js file:

```
exports.findNeededTurnys = function(req, handler)
{
    console.log("findNeededTurnys");
    var key;
    //var arg0 = {$or:[{start:{$lte:new Date()}, $where: "this.users.length == this.seats"}]}; 
    var arg0 = {start:{$lte:new Date()}};
    console.log("findNeededTurnys: arg0="+JSON.stringify(arg0));
    turnydb.collection('turnys', function(err, collection)
    {
        collection.find(arg0, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
            if(err) console.log("findNeededTurnys: find: err="+err);
            console.log("findNeededTurnys: find: result="+JSON.stringify(result));
            handler.handle(result);
        });
    });
};
```

The log files show empty result from MongoDB?:

```
findNeededTurnys: arg0={"start":{"$lte":"2014-03-31T10:17:48.857Z"}}
findNeededTurnys: find: result={}
```

In Mongo, the query works (after adding new Date caller, as driver might abstract that in the js console.log):

```
> db.turnys.find({"start":{"$lte":"2014-03-31T10:17:48.857Z"}});
> db.turnys.find({"start":{"$lte":new Date("2014-03-31T10:17:48.857Z")}});
{ "gId" : ObjectId("5335e4a7b8cf51bcd054b423"), "seats" : 2, "start" : ISODate("2014-03-31T08:47:48.946Z"), "end" : ISODate("2014-03-31T08:49:48.946Z"), "rMin" : 800, "rMax" : 900, "users" : [ ], "_id" : ObjectId("53392bb42b70450000a834d8") }
```

// here is a sample of the mongo db

```
[
  {
    "gId": "5335e4a7b8cf51bcd054b423",
    "seats": 2,
    "start": "2014-03-31T08:47:48.946Z",
    "end": "2014-03-31T08:49:48.946Z",
    "rMin": 800,
    "rMax": 900,
    "users": [],
    "_id": "53392bb42b70450000a834d8"
  },
  {
    "gId": "5335e4a7b8cf51bcd054b423",
    "seats": 2,
    "start": "2014-03-31T08:47:48.946Z",
    "end": "2014-03-31T08:49:48.946Z",
    "rMin": 1000,
    "rMax": 1100,
    "users": [],
    "_id": "53392bb42b70450000a834da"
  },
...
]
```

Comment: It might solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/12084462/2711647

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need any of this wrapping. A date is a **date**:

```js
var zeroth = {$or:[ {start: new Date(), {users:{$size:2}} ]};
```

Now of course if those "dates" in your document are actually "strings" and not proper **date** types then that is your problem. And what you **really** need to to is fix those values so they are real dates.

This applies to **any** language implementation, where you should be working with the native "date" type and let the driver do the conversion for you.

### How to determine if the field is a string

Well the clear difference is when you look at a document in the mongo shell, if it is a real BSON date type then it will look like this:

```js
"start": ISODate("2014-03-31T08:47:48.946Z"),
```

If that is not clear enough then there is the [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator which you can use in a query like this:

```js
db.collection.find({ "start": { "$type": 2 } }).count()
```

It is also **not** MongoDB that is doing this if it is a string, but rather bad implementation in the application or import that was responsible from creating this. Which was what the points made in the initial response were all about.

Comment: Might the problem be the $lt? How do I use that in this case?

What I need:
var zeroth = {$or:[{start:{$lt:new Date()}}, {users:{$size:2}}]}; 

Your solution:
var zeroth = {$or:[{start: new Date()}, {users:{$size:2}}]};

Comment: @mylord The problem pointed out was you seem to be trying to "stringify" the date in all cases, where it **should** be a real date. If you actually **do** have strings for dates in your document then **that** is your real problem. And yes you should always use a range unless you are looking for an very specific date.

Comment: I've clarified and updated the question with details/questions regarding if/how-to-know if MongoDB is storing Date or string. Could you update the answer to help further?

Comment: @mylord There should be enough information added now so you can determine your problem.

Comment: Yes, it was a BSON date (ISODate). Thanks!