# nodejs and mongodb .find command

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im pretty new to the mongodb / node development and I had a quick question.

Typically if I am pulling data out of SQL I could use a WHERE clause and narrow down my results however with mongo I'm not 100% sure how I would go about doing this.

Currently I have a api that responds to get request and its working, it just pulls the entire table.

```
api.get('/', (req, res) => {
    F5.find({}, (err, f5data) => {
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(f5data);
    });
});
```

Inside of the mongodb I have a table that has a column of "time" that is the type of Date.

Im trying to make the .find command to filter out results that are from the current day so from 12am to the current time.

The data looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5eaac0ff2e79d08740f6b1bc",
    "totalConnections": 327,
    "time": "2020-04-30T12:13:51.398Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js to MongoDB: find by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747810/node-js-to-mongodb-find-by-date)

Comment: Unfortunately no I believe that post was about a date being stored as a string then converting it to a date.

Comment: what's your question here? Is it about the query to fetch the data by filtering the date field or something else? Question is not clear.

Comment: Yes i didn't understand the question either, the part what you want to filter.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand `results that are from the current day so from 12am to the current time` I am planning to a give you snippet but i am not sure how you want to filter the dates. I will write few options for you.

```js
F5.find(options)
  .sort({date: -1})
  .then((result) => {
    // do something with the result
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Here i will share some sort options, you can try and test some of them.

```
.sort('-date')
.sort({date: 'desc'})
.sort({date: 'descending'})
.sort([['date', -1]]
```

More information: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort